# How to convert an addEvent function to Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an `addEvent` function and I have a hard time figuring out how to make it work in Typescript without screaming errors. Code at the end.

**The errors:**

`handler()` error:
`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{}' has no compatible call signatures. [2349]`

`e.addEventListener` and others error: `Property 'addEventListener' does not exist on type 'object'.`

I understand those errors, but I have no idea how to tell Typescript that those values are valid.

Typescript version 3.2.2

**The function:**

```
  public addEvent(e:object, evt:string, handler:object ) {
    console.log('_addEvent', e, evt)

    if (evt == 'ready') {
      // Check if the document is already ready
      if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
        console.log('Document is ready')
        handler()
        return false
      } else {
        evt = events.DOMContentLoaded
      }
    }

    if (typeof handler !== 'function') return

    if (e.addEventListener) e.addEventListener(evt, handler, false)
    else if (e.attachEvent) e.attachEvent('on' + evt, handler)
    else {
      var oldHandler = e['on' + evt]
      function newHandler(event) {
        handler.call(e, event)
        if (typeof oldhandler === 'function') oldhandler.call(e, event)
      }
    }
  }
```

**How it's called**
`addEvent(window, 'focus', receiveMessage)`

How can I make Typescript compile?

Thanks

Comment: What kinds of handlers can really be passed here, except for functions, so that the call will be sound? And what is the `e` argument?

Comment: Oh yea I updated the post. `e` is the object on which the event is attached to. `handler` is the callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature" can be fixed by changing the type of `handler` (in the function arguments) to be `Function` instead of `{}` (an object).

The error about `addEventListener` can be resolved by changing the type of `e` (in the function arguments) from `object` to `HTMLElement`. If the TypeScript compiler doesn't know about the `HTMLElement` type, you should be able to resolve that pretty fast with a Google search.

You can, of course, declare `handler` and `e` to be of type `any`. That would be quick, but kind of defeats the purpose of using TypeScript.

Comment: <3 Thanks! I read the basic types in the typecript doc, I tohught I had to stick with basic types. Yes, I want to avoid using `any` at all cost as I switch to TypeScript for types handling. (Flow community seemed lower than TS)

Comment: Glad I could help! The type system in TypeScript is real powerful. Can do much, much more than basic types. On a related note, there are TypeScript type definitions for lots of popular javascript libraries on NPM. Once you've installed the type definitions for one of those libraries, the compiler will make sure you are passing the right kinds of arguments to those functions. See http://definitelytyped.org/

Comment: I appreciate your help, you are awesome.